# DB2 Query to merge 2 decimal column and find max

Tags: db2

I am having two columns in DB2 table ExpiryDate

expiry year - Type decimal and length(4,0)

expiry month - Type decimal and length (2,0)

I need to write one DB2 query to get latest expiry date for that i need to combine both filed year and month and find out latest expiry date.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
select max((expyear * 100) + expmth)
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method:

```
select exp_month, exp_year
from ExpiryDate 
order by exp_year desc, exp_month desc
fetch first rows only
```

Answer (score -1):

You could convert both field to CHAR and concat them or you could try something like this

```
SELECT max(expirymonth)
  FROM table
 WHERE expiryyear = ( SELECT max(expiryyear) 
                        FROM table)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select year, month, date(digits(dec(year, 4))||'-'||digits(dec(month, 2))||'-01') as dt
from table(values 
  (2018, 1)
, (2017, 4)
) t(year, month)
order by dt desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```